# Displaying Different Remote Documents / attachments with different extensions

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently stuck on a phase where I am getting remote attachments like this:

```
[
    {
        "result": "success",
        "homeworks": [
            {
                "submissionID": "1",
                "assignmentID": "75",
                "remark": "saxax",
                "doc_file": "http://skoolroom.co.in/development/uploads/documents/181531183261file.jpg,http://skoolroom.co.in/development/uploads/documents/591531184143file.jpg,http://skoolroom.co.in/development/uploads/documents/601531184144file.jpg,http://skoolroom.co.in/development/uploads/documents/361531184144file.jpg",
                "added_on": "2018-07-08 23:03:52",
                "a_year": "2018-2019"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to present doc_file here. It can be of any extension such as xlsx, jpg, jpeg, pdf, etc.

I have read about Quick Look but all I found was that QuickLook can only be used for the local files. If I download them remotely and store them then display them it will increase the CPU usage as usual.

Comment: You can't display a remote file without first downloading it.

Comment: Have you checked with `UIWebView`?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Yes I have checked UIWebView and I am using that . but isn't there any other option , any third party library will do a work !

Comment: Keep in mind that a web view has to download the file before it can be shown. No matter how you show the file, it has to be downloaded.

Comment: @rmaddy can UIWebView , Show any type of file ? pdf , jpg , jpeg , png?

Comment: Yes, a `UIWebView` can show those file types.